# NextJS - Fullcalendar only loading partly the style

Tags: css, next.js, fullcalendar

I'm trying to implement FullCalendar and importing it in a Nextjs 13 project (T3 Stack) and the style is not loading properly when i navigate for a second time on the page where my FullCalendar component is.

What i'm trying to say is that when i navigate to page on the first render of the component, it loads perfectly with all the style.[Fully loaded Fullcalendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwxNY.png)
But when i go on another page (like the index page) and come back on the calendar page, not all the style is loaded [Partially loaded Fullcalendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XH0pS.png) but only a part (the header).

I tried to load Fullcalendar as dynamic component with SSR disabled (fully loaded on first navigation to page only), as a normal component (fully loaded only if page on which the calendar is reloaded with the browser), as dynamic component with SSR enabled (same as SSR disabled). The style just never load completely.

Comment: Hey @Bdeul, I am using the same stack and facing the same issue. I opened an issue on the FullCalendar repo recently https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/7284

Answer (score 2):

Did you correctly import the fullcalendar script ?

See the doc : https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-globals

If you haven't imported this script:

```
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@6.1.5/index.global.min.js'></script>
```

your style might not work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same issue with the **Fullcalendar** package and **Next.js**.

Versions:

Next.js - 13.5.4
Fullcalendar - 6.1.9

The solution is to add this style tag to the `Head` component in the `_app` file.

```
<style data-fullcalendar></style>
```